# Execution time limit for a Lua script called from the C API

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-api

```
luaL_loadfile(mState, path.c_str());
lua_pcall(mState, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is there a way to put an execution time limit (say 10-20 seconds) for those two C++ statements, that load and then execute a lua file?

Since the Lua file is untrusted I don't want a malicious user to hang the program indefinitely with an infinite loop in the Lua code.

<sup>Tagging C because the Lua API is C, tagging C++ because I'm using C++</sup>

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's lua_sethook which can be used to tell the interpreter to call a hook after every 'count' instructions executed. This way you can monitor the user script and terminate it if it eats up its quota:

```
 int lua_sethook (lua_State *L, lua_Hook f, int mask, int count);
```

This can also be used from Lua:

```lua
debug.sethook(function() print("That's enough for today"); os.exit(0); end, "", 10000)
for i=1,10000 do end
```

If you use the techniques from http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes then you can set up a safe execution environment with `sethook()` and friends entirely from Lua and then switch to sandbox mode while executing the user script. I've tried that here, just for you to get started:

```lua
-- set an execution quota 
local function set_quota(secs)
 local st=os.clock()
 function check() 
  if os.clock()-st > secs then 
    debug.sethook() -- disable hooks
    error("quota exceeded")
  end
 end
 debug.sethook(check,"",100000);
end

-- these are the global objects, the user can use:
local env = {print=print}

-- The user code is allowed to run for 5 seconds.
set_quota(5)

-- run code under environment:
local function run(untrusted_code)
  local untrusted_function, message = loadstring(untrusted_code)
  if not untrusted_function then return nil, message end
  setfenv(untrusted_function, env)
  return pcall(untrusted_function)
end

-- here is the user code:
local userscript=[[
function fib(n) 
 if n<2 then return n
 else return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)
 end
end
for n=1,42 do print(n,fib(n)) end
]]
-- call it:
local r,m=run(userscript)
print(r,m)
```

This should print values of fib() for 5 seconds and then show an error.